# How do I add relationships to an Object in the EmberData (v. 1.13.4) store?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a basket object and many fruit objects. When I want to add a new fruit into a basket how do I add the new fruit into the basket with ember data?

```
store.push('basket', {
                        id: 1,
                        fruits: [3]
                    });
```

This overwrites the existing fruits array in the store, which i don't want.

Is there a way to merge the content of the fruits array? How is this done in a clean and simple way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the fruit object, and not just the id (this is a partial lie).  Assuming you have a reference to the basket and fruit record and fruits is an async property.

```
basket.get('fruits').then(function(fruits){
  fruits.pushObject(fruit);
});
```

Comment: What's the difference between push and pushObject?

Comment: pushObject is the equivalent of a setter for arrays in Ember.  If you just push Ember won't know that the array has changed if it's watching it.